# Is there a large map of Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, map, tatooine

I wanted to make the Tatooine globe with my hands, but I realized that a map of it is probably nowhere, and I would like to know if there is a version (whether it is canon or Legends) of this Atlas map, preferably in high resolution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map from [*Star Wars: Galactic Maps – An Illustrated Atlas of the Star Wars Universe*](https://www.starwars.com/news/charting-the-galaxy-an-interview-with-star-wars-galactic-maps-illustrator-tim-mcdonagh) is below which is canon but the maps are specifically stated not to be entirely accurate.

[image: Star Wars: Galactic Maps the Tatooine map]

There is also the below map which the wikia cites as coming from The Official *Star Wars* Blog and the post "The World of Star Wars: Kenobi," but the page doesn't appear to be archived so I can't check it properly.

[image: The World of Star Wars: Kenobi the Tatooine map]

Comment: I was never 100% certain from the movie if R2 knew exactly where to find Kenobi after landing, but that second map appears to show that he did. An interesting find.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think 2th image is what i looking for. It remains only to find out how to impose it on the sphere evenly, to make it like in the movie

Comment: Kozaky, This suggests that if it were not Jawas grabbing R2, he would have delivered the message to Ben much faster, and he didn’t have to run from the Lars farm across half the planet.

Comment: I've criticised the second map before here. It doesn't make sense given the events of episode 4 (why would Luke say he could only take Ben as far as Anchorhead, if Mos Eisley is closer?)

Comment: How does the Mos Espa Circuit map fit with the latter one? https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/7/78/ITW1_Boonta_Circuit.jpg

Comment: @DanielRoseman In fact, Mos Espa is closer than both of them)